# Nested directives and transclusion

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive where I bind a property using:

`scope: {modelVar: "="}`

The directive template makes use of that variable:

`<input ng-model="modelVar">`

This works great, until I transclude this directive within another directive. Then, the input directive lives in a child scope and the binding with the parent stops working.

The solution I found around was to put modelVar inside some property in the scope. But then, I need to add a controller to my directive and set up my own two-way binding between this new property and the one that is directly in the scope.

Is there a straightforward way to do it so I can avoid the two-way binding?

Please refer to the code here http://plnkr.co/edit/FiyDYLlJQ9aq2KZm5mIg?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive `inputControl` can be simplified as

```
app.directive('inputControl', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div control-container>Input: <input ng-model="$parent.modelVar"></div>',
        scope: {
            'modelVar': '='
        }
    }
});
```

This is the scope diagram

```
[div inputControl] [modelVar]
                       ^
       |               |

[controlContainer] [$parent.modelVar] <-new scope S

       |             |

       transcluded [Value] <- transcluded scope, not isolated scope, it should be sibling of the new scope S
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/w82D3sZNqeNBUgSEOoJt?p=preview)**</kbd>